# Linq query on multiple tables connected by link tables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, subquery

I'm rather new in linq.
I have a table of second hand car that can be published on multiple website. Above that there are multiple images for each car. Websites and images are connected by link tables.

Cartable

- CarID
- Make
- Model

Linktable Website

- CarID
- WebsiteID

Website Table

- WebsiteID
- WebsiteName

Linktable Image

- CarID
- ImageID

Image Tabel

- ImageID
- LocationPath
- AltText

...

I know how to perform a join of the tables but the selection based on the link tables doesn't work

What I Have now

```
    Return From link In AixamReader.Link_Cars_Websites
        Join car In AixamReader.Cars_SecondHandCars 
                On link.SecondHandCarID Equals car.SecondHandCarID
        From imglink In AixamReader.Link_SecondHandCars_Images 
                Where imglink.SecondHandCarID = car.SecondHandCarID
        Join webimg In AixamReader.WebSite_Images 
                On imglink.ImageID Equals webimg.ImageID
                Where link.WebsiteID = pWebsiteID 
                And car.OnWebsite = True
       Select car, webimg
```

How can I select each car for a specific website and then select the first image for each car.

Thx for the help

Comment: is your database is relational data.I means is there primary/foreign keys exists in between tables ?

Comment: Yes database is relationalt with primary and foreign keys working. I can select the first image by car Id on a separate query But I don't know how to apply in combination with the car selection. I want to get it in one datasource for a gridview because otherwise I need to get the image in a separate query on the row.databound event... which in my opinion is not a good way of working...

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
From webSiteCarLink In AixamReader.Link_Cars_Websites

Join car in AixamReader.SecondHandCars
On webSiteCarLink.CarID Equals car.CarID

Join carImageLink In AixamReader.Link_SecondHandCars_Images
On webSiteCarLink.CarID Equals carImageLink.CarID

Join image In AixamReader.WebSite_Images
On carImageLink.ImageID Equals image.ImageID

Where webSiteCarLink.WebsiteID = pWebsiteID 
And car.OnWebsite = True

Group image By Key = car Into imageGroup

Select imageGroup.Key, imageGroup.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I've tried to get this work but I get the error "Definition of method imageGroup is not accesible in this context. I've never worked with group so I'll perform some research on that. Thx a lot